Trino: Exception is not logged (slf4j) in org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection class
I have Trino running and sometimes I have messages like:
http-worker-000 org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection Failed callback

Trino uses jetty for http connections. I have examined Source code from jetty. Trino version is 427, jetty version is 11.0.15. From code it is clear that exception must be logged:
protected void failedCallback(final Callback callback, final Throwable x)
{
    Runnable failCallback = () ->
    {
        try
        {
            callback.failed(x);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LOG.warn("Failed callback", x);
        }
    };

but actual it is not. Any ideas? Maybe some slf4j config are wrong? Any ideas?

What slf4j implementation is your instance using? (I don't recognize that output format)
